# How to disable the effects of clicking outside the edittext

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have a specific button that is meant to be used for editing the `EditText`, ("Done" on the keyboard works as well). So I want to stop touches outside the EditText to hide the soft-keyboard (and whatever other effects it may have).

Is this possible?

Comment: When you touch Edittext , soft keyboard open, and it will keep open when you touch outside of Edittext.

Comment: You are wrong. Maybe that was so in an earlier version of android, not anymore.